# Sitemap for multistore shop

Tags: multistore, sitemaps

As I know, google accept only one sitemap.
So we have a multi store like:

https://www.outdoorequipped.com/ <- entry page
https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/
https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/
https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/
https://www.outdoorequipped.com/work/

How do I set up or create a correct sitemap?

Comment: hm, why do you need different sitemap files??? use mod_rewrite

Comment: And how I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create rewrites in `.htaccess`:
[How to add sitemap.xml for multistore magento](http://www.human-element.com/sitemaps-magento-multistore/)

> First, create a new folder called sitemaps in the root of your website, then create subfolders for each domain.
>   /sitemaps/domain_1/
>   /sitemaps/domain_2/
>
> Then login to the Magento admin and navigate to –
>   catatlog -> google sitemap
>
> Create or edit the sitemap listings for each store and set the “path to sitemap” field to be the path you created for the store.
>
> /sitemaps/domain_1/
>   /sitemaps/domain_2/
>
> Update your `robots.txt` file. To make sure that the search engine spiders are properly directed to the new sitemaps. You may need to update or create the `robots.txt` file. Edit the `robots.txt` file and add the following lines at the top —
>
> ```
> # Website Sitemap
> Sitemap: http://www.domain_1.com/sitemaps/domain_1/sitemap.xml  
> Sitemap: http://www.domain_2.com/sitemaps/domain_2/sitemap.xml
> ```
>
> Finally, if your site uses the Apache web server engine, you should update the `.htaccess` file in the root of your website to direct any other sitemap requests to the proper place.
>   Locate the following line below the line that reads —
>   `RewriteEngine on`
>
> And add the following redirect statements below it —
>
> ```
> # Sitemap: http://www.domain_1.com/sitemaps/domain_1/sitemap.xml
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain_1\.com$
> RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemaps/domain_1/sitemap.xml [NC,L,R=301]
>
> # Sitemap: http://www.domain_2.com/sitemaps/domain_2/sitemap.xml
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain_2\.com$
> RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemaps/domain_2/sitemap.xml [NC,L,R=301]
> ```

Comment: Please do not post the link only, please include any useful information in you post as links to other websites can become broken and future readers cannot read the solution anymore.

Comment: Ok I will write here that info)

Comment: @Mick I hope you dont mind if i copy your suggestion to another question on main stack.

Answer (score 1):

Google allows both multiple sitemaps and one sitemap with urls for multiple domains. The only requirement is that you are the verified owner of all of the sites.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en